# how to wrrite a delay code in c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.0

I need a method for a delay.

I'm looking for something that would allow me to write code similar to this:

```
        for (;;)
        {

            hudElem.SetString("");
            delay(50000);
            hudElem.SetString("");
            delay(50000);
            hudElem.SetString(");
            delay(50000);
            hudElem.SetString("");
            delay(50000);
            hudElem.SetString(");
            delay(50000);
        }
```

waiting 50 secs

I'm Net framework 3.0 so I can't use the Delay method from .NET 4

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(50000);`   (add _using System.Threading;_)

Comment: Next question: Why is my UI not updating?

Comment: The `delay` you're talking about is from the TPL. It's `Task.Delay(50000);` and it's much different than `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: Task.delay for Net 3.5 ?

Comment: Where is your research?  Did you google this?

Comment: To be fair to those with off-the-mark comments, the question should have been tagged with the proper version of .NET given that it's explicitly relevant.

Comment: can some make a small code for delays? for net 3.5

Answer (score -6):

You can use this:

```
async Task Udskyd()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);//miliseconds
        }
```

Just make you button async as well so it will be: private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: `async` and Net 3.x?

Comment: You can't use async in .NET 3.x

Comment: Oh I'm sorry my bad, didn't see you were using 3.0

Comment: @fubo `Task` is what's missing in .NET 3.0 that's the problem.  `async` is a compiler feature, not a runtime feature.

Comment: To be fair, the question should have been tagged with the proper version of .NET given that it's explicitly relevant.

Comment: Indeed, but you still need to call async for the await to work in order